# Within Interactive Brokers, what is the easiest way to 'sync' accounts so that I can execute a trade in multiple accounts from a single transaction?

Tags: stocks, brokerage, online-brokerage, interactive-brokers

My partner and I both have IRA and investment accounts with Interactive Brokers. I manage the investments in our family and so I am currently needing to log into both of our accounts separately in order to execute trades. While our account balances differ, the investment mix is identical between our accounts.

I would like an easier way to manage these accounts. Ideally, I'd be able to say "purchase as many shares of SPY as each account is able, up to 25% of the current available cash." A less ideal but acceptable option would be to have an order screen which shows me each account and I'm able to explicitly say "buy X shares under acct1, Y shares under acct2, etc." or perhaps something as simple as "all accounts should buy 500 shares of AAPL."

Is this something that can be done within IB? I'm vaguely aware of their Advisor platform but that seems to be targeted at, well, advisors with many clients who will have a heterogeneous mix of instruments. I will only be controlling my partner's and my accounts and will be applying a homogeneous asset mix.

Comment: The number of people here using Interactive Brokers might be as low as counting on one hand.  You'd be better served by contacting customer service.  They're pretty good about resolving support issues.